# Firefox: Whitelist TLDs for URI suggestions

Tags: firefox, tld

Current versions of Firefox (I'm on 68) suggests that terms in the address bar that comprise of letters, dots and some special characters (e.g. `-`, `_`) are URIs. Unfortunately, many of programming terms are also in this form, notably namespaces/modules and object properties (e.g. `os.path`, `String.fromCharCode`). Is there any way to only allow TLDs/suffixes of these search terms that match a whitelist (e.g. the [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/) or a user-defined one)?

I'm aware that dots are stripped out of search terms anyways, but it would just help the workflow a bit to not need to do that myself.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your issue directly, but one way to avoid having your searches misinterpreted as URLs is to enclose the entire thing (or a part of it) in "double-quotes". As a fellow programmer who searches for JavaScript APIs sometimes, this is very handy.